# discord.py отправка сообщений в определенное время

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

Код на редактирование. Почему-то не работает, помогите пожалуйста.

[image: Код]

```
from discord.ext import commands
from datetime import datetime, time
import time
import discord
import random

bot = discord.Client()

async def on_ready():
    channel = bot.get_channel(Id_Channel)      #канал куда будут отправляться сообщения
    while True:
        if str(datetime.now().hour) == '9':     #если время 9 утра
            await channel.send('Привет')     #пишет в канал Привет
            time.sleep(4000)     #уходит спать на чуть больше часа
        elif str(datetime.now().hour) == '23':     #если время 23 вечера
            await channel.send('Пока')     #пишет в канал Пока
            time.sleep(4000)     #уходит спать на чуть больше часа
            




token = 'token'
bot.run(token)
```

Comment: 1 - откуда должно браться Id_Channel? 2 - как программа должна узнать, что ей нужно запустить on_ready?

Comment: Приводите конкретные тестовые примеры, пожалуйста. Что на входе, что ожидается на выходе, что на самом деле на выходе. Текст ошибки, если есть, и указание на строку к которой она выдана. Тогда выше шанс получить помощь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вы используете событие, то добавьте @bot.event, чтобы объявить событие.

Например, как должно выглядеть:

```
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    #ваш код
```